# Motif Widgets for Python3

Tags: python-3.x, widget, motif

I am wanting to find Motif widgets for Python3 similar to the popular Python module "PyQt4". I have not found a Motif-widgets module. Do any exist?

Comment: I am not asking for a recommended library. I am wanting to know if such one exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) apparently has [Motif bindings](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/faqmot.htm) so, conceptually, you might be able to build the [development version of WxPython](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ProjectPhoenix), which supports Python 3, from source, with [wxMotif](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/faqmot.htm).

However, even if it this will work, I suspect it won't be an easy process, and unless you have a really good reason for wanting to use Motif, using the Qt bindings (either PyQt or PySide) seems like a much more future proof option, better supported and with a lot more features.